# Use search fields as parameters in script_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

#### Background: the parameter is user-supplied so I can't enable scripting but only script_file.

I'm trying to use a field value as a param,

I will replace the `XXX` below to a field name in the original search result,

```
"script_fields": {
    "my_field": {
        "script_file": "my_test",
        "params": {
          "my_var": "XXX"
        }
    }
}
```

But I couldn't find relevant part [in the document here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html), what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the field in the script.

```
"script_fields": {
    "my_field": {
        "script_file": "myScript",
        "params": {
          "my_var": "fieldName"
        }
    }
}
```

Now from the script use the field name parameter to refer to that field.

```
myScript -
var fieldValue = doc[my_var].value
```

You can read more on the same [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting).